# How do you join a table with a different WHERE condition after you already used a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have 2 tables employees and medical leaves related through the employee ID, basically i want to make a result set where there is one column that filters by month and year, and another column that filters by year only

```
       EMPLOYEES                  MEDICAL
    |employee|ID|             |ID|DateOfLeave|
         A     1                1   2019/1/3
         B     2                1   2019/4/15
         C     3                2   2019/5/16
         D     4


    select employees.employee,Employees.ID,count(medical.dateofleave) as 
    NumberofLeaves
    from employees 
    left outer join Medical on employees.emp = MedBillInfo.emp
    and month(medbillinfo.date) in(1) and year(medbillinfo.date) in (2019)
    group by Employees.employee,employees.ID




           RESULT SET
    |Employee|ID|NumberOfLeaves|YearlyLeaves|--i want to join this column
        A      1      1              2
        B      2      0              1
        C      3      0              0
        D      4      0              0
```

But i have no idea how to write inside the current sql statement to join a yearly leaves column to my current result set which is only employee,id and numberofleaves

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. Try `group by employees.employee, Employees.ID`.

Comment: BTW, you ORDER BY an unknown column!?!

Comment: @jarlh Oops the statement was originally meant for my other database, i just edited it to fit the example database above, forgot to edit the bottom rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select e.employee, e.ID,
       count(*) as num_leaves,
       sum(case when month(m.date) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_leaves_in_month_1
from employees e left join
     Medical m
     on e.emp = m.emp
where m.date >= '2019-01-01' and m.date < '2020-01-01'
group by e.employee, e.ID;
```

Notes:

- This removes the `where` clause which seems to refer to a non-existent table alias.
- The date arithmetic uses direct comparisons rather than functions.
- This introduces table aliases so the question is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Oh i see thanks, but for my case i will have to remove the where clause as I have data that will eventually be added in 2020, and i want to have the flexibility to be able to choose which YearlyLeaves i want to see. Can i ask if there are advantages to using direct comparisons for the date compared to functions?

Comment: @guyguy . . . Direct comparisons are more easily understood by the optimizer.  They also allow the optimizer to take advantage of partitions and indexes on those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your question probably needs to be corrected as the group by condition does not match with select columns. But based on what you asked, I think you need to use truncate date function in order to group the leaves by year. For SQL Server, there is YEAR(date) function which returns the year of the given date. This date would be MEDICAL.DateOfLeave in your case.

Comment: Oops thanks for the heads up, the statement was originally meant for my other database, i just edited it to fit the example database above, forgot to edit the bottom rows